# UIManagedDocument example / tutorial

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, icloud, uimanageddocument

I have been trying very unsuccessfully to create a simple `UIManagedDocument` library style application (separate documents saved to iCloud).

I am confused with the following:

Do I subclass `UIManagedDocument` and set up the `persistentStoreCoordinator`, `ManagedObjectModel` & `ManagedObjectContext` within this subclass, or are these supposed to be configured within the `AppDelegate` (and if so, how do I go about refreshing the `persistentStoreCoordinator` to look at the new file - it seems that once that has read a `persistentStore` that I can't get it to read a new persistent store)?

Comment: Here is a link to an example, includes a video showing the app working. http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/uimanageddocument-icloud-integration/

Answer (score 0):

Richard's example is an excellent example. I used it and the PragmaProg book on core data http://pragprog.com/book/mzcd2/core-data as a guide for creating my managed document module on github. 
See: https://github.com/dtrotzjr/APManagedDocument

My code makes use of iOS 7 iCloud Core Data behavior which I cannot comment on publicly until the NDA is lifted. Feel free to ping me directly if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

I've just posted a project based on Rick Warren's example: [MultiDocumentPlusUUID](https://github.com/DonBriggs/MultiDocumentPlusUUID). In his "Syncing Multiple Core Data Documents Using iCloud" post, Rick writes:

> Another bug often shows up when I start trying to pass changes back and forth between devices that both have the same file open. The first sync always seems to work--and it seems to work pretty well as long as each subsequent sync is in the same direction.

MultiDocumentPlusUUID compiles and runs on iOS 7.1b4, and can ping-pong updates to a given document successfully.