# It is possible to download files from iCloud drive?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, icloud, icloud-drive

Suppose we have an image file called "myImage.png" and I added this file on my iCloud drive through the website www.icloud.com.

For this I test many codes like [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6015/beginning-icloud-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1),  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760236/method-for-downloading-icloud-files-very-confusing), and finally try to use the command **startDownloadingUbiquitousItemAtURL** and none of them worked (I can download the files only if exist inside this path below:)

> /Users/mynamemac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/07BAC437-D32A-44BB-BC25-5683222B7516/data/Library/Mobile%20Documents/

Knowing that I would like to take the file storage in my iCloud Drive and save in my directory, how I can download this file and save on my device?

Comment: Is it possible to share link via iCloud using any iCloud apis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you should turn on iCloud drive first, add this to your `info.plist` file.

```
<key>NSUbiquitousContainers</key>
<dict>
    <key>iCloud.com.example.MyApp</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSUbiquitousContainerIsDocumentScopePublic</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSUbiquitousContainerSupportedFolderLevels</key>
        <string>Any</string>
        <key>NSUbiquitousContainerName</key>
        <string>MyApp</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Then, you should turn on `iCloud` under the `Capabilites` tab of your project. `XCode` will add the entitlements for you automatically.
You can use this code to check whether you have access to iCloud or not.
`[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];`
You should refer to [iCloud Design Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/iCloudDesignGuide.pdf) for more information.

Comment: That iCloud Design Guide link isn't working. Try: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/Introduction.html